# oracle connect by prior,how to indicate the highest score from the path- using sys_connect_by_path

Tags: sql, oracle, hierarchical-query

I try to use sys_connect_by_path in connect by prior, to create a path for all the model, I want to indicate for any path the highest score that the client gets in the models.

[this is my table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UREAh.png)

the query that  I use to create the paths

```
select id, sys_connect_by_path(model,';') path,
       sys_connect_by_path(score,';') score_path, max_score   
from table
connect by prior id = id
```

[example of result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EOhVp.png)

for any path I get the last score from the path, how can I indicate the highest score from the path?
there is a "max" function?

Comment: Query you posted is invalid for at least two reasons: a) syntax error (PRIOR, not PROIR), b) loop in user data. As of data you posted: where did "0.5" come from (in result)? There's no such value in "input" data (the 1st screenshot).

Comment: hi tnx for your response I can't upload the original code or tables... 
the "proior" is "prior" and the 0.5 is a mistake its suppose to be 0.85 
I made some change up there (hope there are no mistake now.... lol)